# How to convert json schema to avro schema

Tags: json, avro, jsonschema, avro-tools

My application has been using json schema (org.everit.json.schema.Schema ) to validate JSON messages whether they comply to a particular format. We are now thinking of moving to the Avro schema. This involves converting previously-stored schema.json files to be converted to Avro schema schema.avsc. Also, the current behavior is we get schema in JSON format via an API /schema/create and store it schema.json format after validating it using SchemaLoader, for example, SchemaLoader.load(JSONObject obj).

We also need a way to convert this schema.json to schema.avsc as we receive it run time via API. Is there any utility/tool we can use to convert the schema.json to schema.avsc?